# Could an ecosystem exist where no rain falls (only snow and ice)?

Tags: environment, life

I am trying to create a boreal, alien ecosystem loosely based on Northern Siberia. Liquid rain never falls here, since snow and hail fall instead for most of the year, and the short, hot summers- the only time temperatures rise above freezing- are arid and without any precipitation whatsoever. Terrestrial organisms in this ecosystem can either get water from snow directly, drink from unfrozen patches of lakes and rivers, or take their fill when the snow melts in the summer. Water (at least in liquid, drinkable form) is often scarce.

Since liquid rain normally never falls, the native creatures are mystified when sudden global warming causes drinkable water to start falling freely from the sky instead of snow.

Is it feasible for this environment to exist in a state that allows for complex life?

Comment: You could easily have such an ecosystem in the mountains or on a high plateau on Earth.  Does your ecosystem need to span the entirety of your planet?

Comment: @Willk No, just in one area in the planet's arctic circle. The important bit that I'm not sure works on Earth is that it cannot precipitate at all in the summer. As in, it is not just extremely rare, it's completely impossible.

Comment: What exactly is the worldbuilding problem you're trying to solve --- this seems to describe some parts of Earth pretty well.

Comment: What your describing is too simplistic. Even in sub-freezing weather, sunlight can heat the ground enough for snow to melt. And when it doesn't, snow still sublimates to water vapor. Plants depend on both in Real Life to sustain themselves through to summer (plants still require watering even during the winter months). I believe your real problem is that even plants that survive harsh, cold weather require some time above freezing to grow and propagate. They might survive what you describe if the soil is clay on top and sandy underneath for a high water table.

Comment: Consequently, while aspects of what your describing exist in Real Life, I believe it's not possible in Real Life to have exactly what you're describing. Is that really necessary? Our job here is to help you create the rules of an imaginary world. If you're really trying to crowbar an idea into the Real World, it might make more sense to ask over at [earthscience.se]. If, on the other hand, you really are making an imaginary world, then whether or not the ecosystem is plausible on Earth is irrelevant, right?

Comment: What you should be asking is, "I want X and I've done Y to achieve it, but it's not working the way I want because of Z. What can I do?" Plausibility or whether or not something "can exist" (which always can on your imaginary world and can't always on Earth, which is the one and only data point we have to work with in Real Life) is irrelevant. What is, is suspension of disbelief. I think you have that.

Comment: @JBH That’s good enough for me I think. For what it’s worth, the temperature rises above freezing for a couple of months, but it’s during the “dry” season. This is pretty close to what seems to occur in Siberia anyway based on my research, there’s just no liquid rainfall in my version instead of very little. Not sure if there’s a mechanic I can use to explain that.

Answer (score 6):

You can get rid of the Summer altogether. Just make it "very freezing" to "just freezing"; so it is not possible for rain to fall.

But as was mentioned by JBH, sunlight can still heat the ground, when it is "just freezing", enough to melt the snow.

You can also make your plants evolve some thermoconductivity so leaves can absorb and store heat from the sunlight, and then snowfall on the leaves will melt and be absorbed. To do that, make the leaves pitch black, and salty; both dark colors and salt are very good at absorbing and retaining heat from light.

If you don't like Black leaves, maybe Red, if you must reflect a color red is a low energy color, you want to absorb the higher energies (frequencies) in the color spectrum. Conduct the heat to internal salty sap for storage, that is what keeps the leaves from freezing too solid.

So the idea is, you have intermittent snowfall (not every day, and it doesn't have to be year round), a snowflake falls on the leaf, it melts, the water is absorbed. During the day with sunlight, the leaves get recharged with warmth by the sunlight.

But it never rises above freezing, and never rains: It just gets close.

Then some sort of global warming may push it above freezing, so liquid rain starts falling. That shouldn't affect the forest too much I wouldn't think, the leaves had to melt the snow to absorb the water, now they don't but could still absorb water. They would not behave differently.

But now you have issues with runoff and such.

Also I did not address snow accumulation; but it might be reasonable, as JBH said, for sunlight to also warm fallen snow enough to melt it into the ground.

You just cannot have it snow every day; you need some sort of cycle to deal with the snowfall, or it will literally build up to be tens of kilometers thick, as it is at the Earth's poles. The tallest tree in the world is only 380 feet tall (about 116 meters), and constant snow can accumulate much faster than a tree can grow. You need to average near zero snow on the ground in your snow/melt cycle, or perhaps an inch a year.

Comment: If it never rises above freezing, then how does evaporation happen for there to be any precipitation at all?

Comment: @komodosp The same way it does on Earth, the oceans evaporate where it is warm enough, the vapor rises and circulates due to the rotation of the Earth with an uneven surfaces, various rising and sinking hot and cold air in various places, currents of rivers and oceans, etc. This tends to form regular long-lasting features, like the Gulf Current, or other regular currents that create deserts or forests. Some of that water vapor makes it North, toward colder territory, and due to temperature differentials and such will precipitate on our cold red forest. Global Warning will disrupt these flows.

Answer (score 4):

**No axial tilt.  Seasons are due to eccentric orbit.**

Earth seasons are because of axial tilt.  The poles take turns being closer and farther from the sun.

https://www.weather.gov/lmk/seasons

[image: seasons and axis diagram]

> The earth's spin axis is tilted with respect to its orbital plane.
> This is what causes the seasons. When the earth's axis points towards
> the sun, it is summer for that hemisphere. When the earth's axis
> points away, winter can be expected. Since the tilt of the axis is 23
> 1/2 degrees, the North Pole never points directly at the Sun, but on
> the summer solstice it points as close as it can, and on the winter
> solstice as far as it can.

With no tilt there is more uniform heating of your planet at all times of year.  The equator is still warmer and the poles cooler because the planet is round and so the equator bulges closer to the sun.

The no axial tilt thing is because alternating seasons on the poles might make one of them warm enough for it to rain.

---

Your planet has seasons.  It is the same season everywhere on the planet.  Your seasons are because of orbital eccentricity.

Earth's orbit is nearly circular.  The planet is about the same distance from the sun at all times of year.  A small increase in eccentricity leads to large changes in solar energy delivered over the year.

https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/earth-and-planetary-sciences/eccentricity

> Earth's orbital eccentricity e quantifies the deviation of Earth's
> orbital path from the shape of a circle. It is the only orbital
> parameter that controls the total amount of solar radiation received
> by Earth, averaged over the course of 1 year. The present eccentricity
> of Earth is e ≈ 0.01671. In the past, it has varied between 0 and
> ∼0.06. The eccentricity value can be used to compute the difference in
> the distance from Earth to the Sun between their closest and furthest
> approaches (perihelion and aphelion); presently, this amounts to 2e ≈
> 3.3%. At maximum eccentricity, the annual variation of solar insolation due to eccentricity is thus 24%.

Your planet has more eccentric orbit such that solar energy delivered in summer (closest approach to star) and winter (furtherst from star) differs by 300%.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_eccentricity

[image: eccentric orbits]

It does not rain in summer because as the planet heats in its entirety, the ability of the atmosphere to hold moisture increases.    The moisture evaporates and stays in the air.   Hot air holds more moisture, which I remember because your breath is hot, and it holds moisture, but in cool outside air the moisture in your breath condenses out as it cools, and you can see those droplets as fog.
At the poles a lot of melting snow makes it into the ground.  Plants can grow at the poles during the short summer and into autumn.

Because of the equatorial bulge and distance from the star, day and night temperatures differ most at the equator.   As summer ends and the planet moves away from the sun, at night it cools enough that the air cannot hold all the moisture it accumulated in the day.  It rains a lot at the equator in autumn.  This pulls moisture laden air from the poles and so precipitation there is delayed until later in the year.

By the time the autumn storms settle down the situation reverses.  It is cold enough at the poles for most of the year that little water evaporates.  The equator is still warm enough for water to evaporate and moisture laden air moves north and drops off its water as snow as it cools.

Thus:
1:  Homogenous seasons planetwide.

2:  Warmer at the equator, cooler at the poles.

3. Water cycles:  Dry summer everywhere.  Rainy equatorial autumn.  Snowy polar winter and spring.

Comment: Seasons, and equator being warmer than poles has nothing to do with distance from the sun... In fact, those differences are negligible compared to the distance between the planet and the star (and far smaller than difference because of eccentric orbit). Reason for temperature differences lies in the angle of sunlight. On equator you get sunlight at almost 90 degrees, so the power density is higher than at pole, where angle is far smaller.

Answer (score 1):

There are ecosystems in which there is essentially no precipitation ever.  This is why Egypt is the "Gift of the Nile."

Snow and ice make it easier.  The geology of the land has to be such that the water does not just run off when it melts.  Ideally there would be places that were positively soggy after the snow melt, but as long as enough is retained to live, life will do so.

In that brief season, there are plants and animals that seize the day and do all their living.  This can be quite strenuous; in North America, the skunk cabbage is capable of melting the snow to break through and start its very early flowering.